# length of code unclear while looping through it

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a python dataset as a list where each individual entry in the list is another list containing an x and y value. I am trying to calculate the mean for all the ys at the different x values (stored in another list).

```
data_set = [[1,25],[1,30],[1,35],[1,40],[1,45]
           ,[2,35],[2,40],[2,44],[2,50],[2,55],[2,58]
           ,[3,49],[3,54],[3,60],[3,64],[3,68]
           ,[4,50],[4,63],[4,65],[4,73],[4,78],[4,83],[4,85]
           ,[5,72],[5,77],[5,80],[5,86],[5,88],[5,95]]
```

But I cannot get the code to loop through the entire dataset.

```
def prf_mean(list):
    mean_list = []
    temp_list = []


    counter = 1
    for i in list:

        if i[0]==counter:
            temp_list.append(i) 
        else:
            temp_var = 0
            for i in temp_list:
                temp_var +=i[1]

            mean_list.append(temp_var / len(temp_list))
            temp_list.clear()
            counter += 1

    return (mean_list)


prf_mean(data_set)
```

The code provides an accurate mean for x = 1 but for any higher x the results are wrong (because they are divided by the wrong number) and x = 5 is not shown at all.

Comment: It is not showing the result for x=5 because it will enter into if part for it's last value and then the loop will stop. Also, is it necessary to keep [x,y] for inner list can't it be just list of y? because x is only displaying index and you want to calculate mean for y value only.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a dictionary as your data structure for this problem. Below example converts your data_set to a dictionary then calculates mean y for each x.

```py
data_set = [[1,25],[1,30],[1,35],[1,40],[1,45]
           ,[2,35],[2,40],[2,44],[2,50],[2,55],[2,58]
           ,[3,49],[3,54],[3,60],[3,64],[3,68]
           ,[4,50],[4,63],[4,65],[4,73],[4,78],[4,83],[4,85]
           ,[5,72],[5,77],[5,80],[5,86],[5,88],[5,95]]

# Convert data_set to dictionary
data_set_dict = {}
for x, y in data_set:
    if x not in data_set_dict:
        data_set_dict[x] = []
    data_set_dict[x].append(y)

# Calculate mean y for each x in dictionary
for x, ys in data_set_dict.items():
    print(f'X: {x}, Mean Y: {sum(ys)/len(ys)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you sort your items (or if you can depend on them being sorted as they are now) you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group them into units based on the x value. Then just find the average of each group:

```
from itertools import groupby

data_set = [[1,25],[1,30],[1,35],[1,40],[1,45]
           ,[2,35],[2,40],[2,44],[2,50],[2,55],[2,58]
           ,[3,49],[3,54],[3,60],[3,64],[3,68]
           ,[4,50],[4,63],[4,65],[4,73],[4,78],[4,83],[4,85]
           ,[5,72],[5,77],[5,80],[5,86],[5,88],[5,95]]

for k, g in groupby(sorted(data_set), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    n = [x[1] for x in g]
    av = sum(n)/len(list(n))
    print (f"{k} average: {av}")
```

This prints:

```
1 average: 35.0
2 average: 47.0
3 average: 59.0
4 average: 71.0
5 average: 83.0
```

Because groupby is an iterator, if your data is already sorted you could potentially calculate the means without ever having the entire dataset in memory which is nice if it's large — for example when reading it off disk.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way.

```
data_set = [[1,25],[1,30],[1,35],[1,40],[1,45]
           ,[2,35],[2,40],[2,44],[2,50],[2,55],[2,58]
           ,[3,49],[3,54],[3,60],[3,64],[3,68]
           ,[4,50],[4,63],[4,65],[4,73],[4,78],[4,83],[4,85]
           ,[5,72],[5,77],[5,80],[5,86],[5,88],[5,95]]

all_means = {}
for i in range(1, 6):
    means = []
    for j in data_set:
        if j[0] == i:
            means.append(j[1])
    all_means[i] = sum(means) / len(means)

print(all_means)
```

Output:

```
{1: 35.0, 2: 47.0, 3: 59.0, 4: 71.0, 5: 83.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the functional programming way:

```
data_set = [[1,25],[1,30],[1,35],[1,40],[1,45]
           ,[2,35],[2,40],[2,44],[2,50],[2,55],[2,58]
           ,[3,49],[3,54],[3,60],[3,64],[3,68]
           ,[4,50],[4,63],[4,65],[4,73],[4,78],[4,83],[4,85]
           ,[5,72],[5,77],[5,80],[5,86],[5,88],[5,95]]

f = lambda arg, n: list(map(lambda k: list(map(lambda j: j[1], 
    list(filter(lambda i: i[0] == k, arg)))), range(1, n + 1)))

for i in f(data_set, 5):
    print(sum(i) / len(i))
```

**Output:**

```
35.0
47.0
59.0
71.0
83.0
```